# Laravel Factories - How to save nested relationships

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-seeding, factories

I was working with laravel factories and stuck with nested relation ships.
For example a user may have many posts and a post has many comments.
i was able to save posts with user by each() method but was not able to save comments with posts

```
$users = factory(App\User::class, 3)->create()
    ->each(function ($user) {
        $user->posts()->saveMany(factory(App\Post::class, 5)->make());
    });
```

as save() method accepts array so i must have to use make() method with posts but now i can't attach comments with the posts.
after hour of searching i could not fond the solution but now i have solved it.
I am posting it in answers for the fellows who are looking for the solution and please update me if there have more decent solution to this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i solve this:

```
$users = factory(App\User::class, 3)->create()
        ->each(function ($user) {
            $user->posts()->saveMany(factory(App\Post::class, 5)->make());
        });
foreach ($users as $user){
  foreach ($user->posts as $post){
    $post->comments()->saveMany(factory(App\Comment::class, 5)->make());
  }
}
```